# How to find most frequent triplet of integers?

Tags: rgb, triplet

I have a class containing 3 integers: r,g,b. I make table of 50 objects to that class. How to find most frequent triplet?

I made arrays of every value r,g,b. Then I sorted them and found most frequent value of each array.

Comment: please post your code, sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Sort all your objects by RGB. Then just start at the beginning and count the duplicates.